# Synchronized call of functions using std::condition_variable

Tags: c++, concurrency, synchronization, mutex, deadlock

I got addicted to learning concurrency again and tried to solve [this problem](https://leetcode.com/problems/print-in-order/).

In short, I have a class and 3 functions. I need to sync their calls (need to print `FirstSecondThird`).

It will become more clear with the code below:

```
std::function<void()> printFirst = []() { std::cout << "First"; };
std::function<void()> printSecond = []() { std::cout << "Second"; };
std::function<void()> printThird = []() { std::cout << "Third"; };

class Foo {
    std::condition_variable cv;
    bool mfirst,msecond;
    std::mutex mtx;
public:
    Foo() {
        mfirst = false;
        msecond = false;
    }

    void first(std::function<void()> printFirst) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
        printFirst();
        mfirst = true;
    }

    void second(std::function<void()> printSecond) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
        cv.wait(l, [this]{return mfirst == true; });
        printSecond();
        msecond = true;
    }

    void third(std::function<void()> printThird) {
        std::unique_lock<std::mutex> l(mtx);
        cv.wait(l, [this] {return (mfirst && msecond) == true; });
        printThird();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo t;

    std::thread t3((&Foo::third, t, printThird));
    std::thread t2((&Foo::second, t, printSecond));
    std::thread t1((&Foo::first, t, printFirst));

    t3.join();
    t2.join();
    t1.join();

    return 0;
}
```

And guess what my output is? It prints `ThirdSecondFirst`.

How is this possible?  Isn't this code prone to DEADLOCK? I mean, when the first thread acquired the mutex in function `second`, wouldn't it wait forever because now as mutex is acquired we cannot change variable `mfirst`?

Comment: [`cv.wait()` unlocks the mutex](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/condition_variable/wait) while waiting, allowing another thread to acquire it

Comment: thanks @RemyLebeau, now I understand that it couldnt cause deadlock.
But how it can call Third before all above? Shouldnt cv wait for booleans to become true?

Comment: Your code is not calling `cv.notify_all()` or `cv.notify_one()` to notify waiting threads that `cv` has been signaled so they can stop waiting and re-acquire the mutex lock to check their predicate conditions. After calling `mfirst = true;` and `msecond = true;` you need to notify `cv`. Calling `cv.wait()` without `cv.notify_...()` defeats the whole purpose of using a `conditional_variable` at all

Comment: still, I cannot understand how the thread is passing this line:
cv.wait(l, [this] {return (mfirst && msecond) == true; });

Comment: Read the documentation I linked to in my earlier comment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a very subtle bug.

```
std::thread t3((&Foo::third, t, printThird));
```

This line does not do what you expect. It initializes a thread with only one argument, `printThird`, instead of initializing with the 3 arguments you specified. That's because you accidentally used a [comma expression](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other). As a result, `&Foo::third` and `t` are just discarded, and the member functions are never even called.

The only functions that are called in your code are `printFirst`, `printSecond`, and `printThird`. Without any synchronization, they may print in arbitrary order. You may even get interleaved output.

```
std::thread t3{&Foo::third, t, printThird};
```

Here is the corrected version. The curly braces are for avoiding the compiler treating this as a function declaration because of [most vexing parse](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse)

As a side note, as mentioned in the comments, you are using condition variables wrong.

Comment: Just remove the extra parentheses. I'll update my answer

Comment: actually there was a reason putting 2 parentheses as the compiler was interpreting as a function declaration.

Comment: Right. Then you could use curly braces or copy initialization.

Comment: yeah I did already, although wasn't very clear for me why the first 2 arguments were discarded.  Thank you

Comment: Becuase of the comma operator. Basically, if you write `int a = (++x, y);`, then `++x` is evaluated and discarded, and `a` is equal to `y`. You can read more here https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_other

Comment: I read that, but is there a rule under which compiler interprets as , operator?
Like I am passing arguments to thread constructor, how come they can be discarded?

Comment: Well, if I understand correctly, according to the standard, you are passing just one argument.